# Graph API Onedrive approot created as "Microsoft Graph"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I registered my application in Application Registration Portal and set the application permissions in Microsoft Graph Permissions to acquire **`Files.ReadWrite.All` (Admin Only)**. So that I can gain access to all users in the organization using admin consent.

With the token I acquired, I am able to call API endpoints without any problem.

Then I tried to access the `approot` for a specific user. I sent the GET request to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}/drive/special/approot
```

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/special-folders-appfolder), when I call the endpoint, it should create a folder inside the Apps folder in users OneDrive, with the name of my application as I registered it in App Registration Portal.

The problem is that the folder created has the name as "Microsoft Graph" instead of my application name.

How can I create the app folder with my application's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/special-folders-appfolder):

> The App Folder is a dedicated, special folder for your app. The App Folder is typically named after your app, and is found in the Apps folder in the user's OneDrive. If you request the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` permission scope and the user authorizes it, your app gets read and write access to this folder.

It is also worth note `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` is only applicable to Personal accounts (OneDrive), it does not work for Work/School accounts (OneDrive for Business). From the [Permissions documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#remarks-5):

> The `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` delegated permission is only valid for personal accounts and is used for accessing the App Root special folder with the OneDrive Get special folder Microsoft Graph API.

*As aside, the docs here are admittedly confusing and sometimes seem to contradict themselves. I've opened an issue in the documentation repo to see if the topic of permission could be addressed better.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any workaround to create app folder for work/school account?

Comment: Not at the moment. There is an [issue filed in GitHub](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/682) that talks about this issue.

Comment: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/33911101-make-files-readwrite-appfolder-work-with-onedrive